# Multiply only negative numbers and output only negative integers from a file in C

Tags: c, file, while-loop, output, scanf

I need to multiply *only* negative numbers from file with content: `12 7 -14 3 -8 10`. So i need to *-14 multiply by -8*.
Here is my full code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
FILE *in, *out;
int x, negative, product;
in=fopen("C:\\Users\\emachines\\Desktop\\ind\\in.txt", "r");
if(in==NULL) //If file failed to open
{
printf ("Cannot open the file. Exiting...");
return -1;
}

printf("Numbers are:"); //Output integers
while(fscanf(in, "%d", &x)==1)
{
printf("%d ", x); //end of outputting integers
}

printf("\nNegative numbers are:"); //Output negative numbers
while(!feof(in)) 
{
fscanf(in, "%d", &negative);
while(negative<0)
{
printf("%d", negative); //end of outputting negative numbers
                        //multiply negative numbers
printf("mupltipying... Product - %d", product)
}
}

fclose(in);
return(0); //main returns int
}
```

So how to multiply only negative numbers? And how to output *only* *negative* numbers, if i used x variable for outputting *all* number? 
sorry for my english

Comment: Please format your code properly in order to make it readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check while printing the numbers if it is less than 0 print it and at the same time make product of this number. Here is you working code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
FILE *in, *out;
int x, negative, product=1;
in=fopen("a.txt", "r");
if(in==NULL) //If file failed to open
{
printf ("Cannot open the file. Exiting...");
return -1; 
}
printf("Negative Numbers are:"); //Output integers
while(fscanf(in, "%d", &x)==1)
{
    if(x<0){
        product*=x;
        printf("%d ", x); //end of outputting integers
    }
}

printf("\n");
                        //multiply negative numbers
printf("mupltipying...\n Product=%d\n", product);
//printf("%d\n",product );


fclose(in);
return(0); //main returns int
}
```

Comment: I used a.txt just for debugging you code.you can change it. :)

Comment: Thanks. I tried to use that part of code with another part of code, which outputting all integers. Now i see why it didn't work.
`printf("Negative Numbers are:"); //Output negative integers
while(fscanf(in, "%d", &x)==1)
{
    if(x<0){
        product*=x;
        printf("%d ", x); //end of outputting negative integers
    }
}
printf("\nProduct=%d", product);`
 But why I can't simultaneously output all my integers, then output only negative integers, and the multiply negative integers?

Comment: You can do that also. All you need to do is either re-read the file and print all the numbers or store the numbers in an array and later print it.

Answer (score 0):

You need only one loop where you have to include if statement that will check whether a next number is negative.

For example

```
long long product = 1;

//...

while ( fscanf( in, "%d", &x ) == 1 )
{
    if ( x < 0 )
    {
        printf( "%d ", x );
        product *= x;
    }
}
```